# Rails: Query parents with grandchildren (associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**Using Rails how can I:**

1.Return all `users` with `questions`? eg.

```
@users_with_questions = User.joins(:question).where.not(question: { id: nil })
```

2.Return all `users` with `answers`?

Comment: all parents with children, for example ? [jack,john, steven] returns [jack_parrent, john_parent, steeven_parent]. is it what you want ?

Comment: in ruby? or with a single sql query?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: add an example exactly what do you want

Comment: I have tried to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but i think you do not need this kind of model architecture for these relations. This can be simply done with only 1 class `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` which `has_many :children` with self-join. This way you can go as deep into the hierarchy as you want. You will not be limited to just the 3 levels of children.

Comment: The modal/class names are examples only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Return all users with questions?

```
@users_with_questions = User.includes(:question).where.not(:question => {id: nil})
```

2.Return all users with answers?

```
@users_with_answers = User.includes(question: :answer).where.not(:answer => {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
children = Child.where( #something)
children_parents = Parent.joins(:children).where(children: {id: children} )

grandchildren = Grandchildren.where(#something)
grandchildren_parents = Parent.joins(children: :grandchildren).where(grandchildren: {id: grandchildren})
```

so for your example:

```
grandchildren_parents = Parent.joins(children: :grandchildren).where.not(grandchildren: {id: nil}).distinct
```

or

```
grandchildren_parents = Parent.includes(children: :grandchildren).where.not(grandchildren: {id: nil})
```

Comment: This returns a parent record for every grandchilren, resulting in duplicates

Comment: The `includes` method would achieve this without the need for `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

In ruby:

```
@users_with_questions = User.all.select{|u| u.questions.present? }
@users_with_answers   = User.all.select{|u| u.questions.present? && u.answers.present? }

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions
end
```

In one sql query (just one way of doing it):

```
@users_with_questions = User.find(Question.pluck(:user_id).uniq!)
questions = Question.find(Answer.pluck(:question_id).uniq!)
@users_with_answers = User.find(questions.pluck(:user_id).uniq!)
```

Comment: thx for your answer: `@users_with_questions = User.find(Question.pluck(:user_id).uniq!)` won't this hurt performance with a large data set?

Comment: Yes quite possibly... keep in mind this answer is three years out of date now ;)
There are neater ways of doing it such that rails builds the query fully before sending any request to the db.